# How to use forward slashes instead of a hash (#) in history.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

I am using a [history.js plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) and would like to know how I can implement a `/` type of URL. Right now my code is:

```
//Check if url hash value exists (for bookmark)
$.history.init(pageload);   

//highlight the selected link
$('a[href=' + document.location.hash + ']').addClass('selected');

//Seearch for link with REL set to ajax
$('a[rel=ajax]').click(function () {

    //grab the full url
    var hash = this.href;

    //remove the # value
    hash = hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');

    //for back button
    $.history.load(hash);   

    //clear the selected class and add the class class to the selected link
    $('a[rel=ajax]').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    //hide the content and show the progress bar
    $('#content').hide();
    $('#loading').show();

    //run the ajax
    getPage();

    //cancel the anchor tag behaviour
    return false;
}); 



function pageload(hash) {
    //if hash value exists, run the ajax
    if (hash) getPage();    
}



function getPage() {

//generate the parameter for the php script
var data = 'page=' + document.location.hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
$.ajax({
    url: "route.php",  
    type: "GET",        
    data: data,     
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {  

        //hide the progress bar
        $('#loading').hide();   

        //add the content retrieved from ajax and put it in the #content div
        $('#content').html(html);

        //display the body with fadeIn transition
        $('#content').fadeIn('slow');       
    }       
});
}
```

The URL is always `http://localhost/test/index.php#page1` but I would like to know how to make it `http://localhost/test/page1`.

I don't want it to show the index.php part either, I need it just like the URL above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can only be done using HTML5 and [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

That API allows you to change the displayed URL (so long as it's in the same domain) without triggering a page load.  You can then use AJAX to change the displayed content instead.

To see it in action, browse any source tree on github.com - they use the technique to "slide in" the source code as you browse the files.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but is there a plugin that can help me do this? Just like history.js?

Comment: @randomphp I don't know, I just coded what I needed by hand.  It's not at all difficult.

Answer (score 1):

> But the URL is always a http://localhost/test/index.php#page1 but I
>   would like to know how to make it http://localhost/test/page1

That not what you want. Changing the window.location would cause the document to reload.

That why you would use the hash to store application state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but then how does facebook do this? They have AJAX browsing for the entire site and they don't use hashes. I know Twitter uses the Hashbang style (which is said to be a bad thing) but how does facebook do it?